# Python Loop synchronization

Tags: python

I am calling an external process multiple times, in a loop. To give you a pseudocode:

```
for i in xrange(1, 100):
    call external proc which inserts a row into a table
```

The problem here is, whenever the external process is called, it runs in a seperate thread, which could take any amount of time to run. So, python would have continued with the execution. This causes the insertion to run into a row lock and prevent insertion.

What is the ideal way to wait for the process to complete, under the following constraints:

1. I cannot modify the way the external process works.
2. I know I can, but I do not want to use a hack, like thread.sleep
3. I cannot modify any DB settings.

The code for calling the external proc is:

```
def run_query(query, username, password):
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen( "<path to exe> -u " + username + " -p "+ password +" " + query, 
                                     shell = True,
                                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
        result, error = process.communicate()
        if error != '':
             _pretty_error('stderr', error)
    except OSError, error:
        _pretty_error('OSError', str(error))
    return result
```

Comment: Can you show us the Python code for `call external proc which inserts a row into a table`?

Comment: Added it to my original question

Comment: Just for the record / for the general reader here from Google: if you're **not** forced to make 1 subprocess call per record update—if your interface supports the [Database API's `executemany`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id23)—*that* would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options according to the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) documentation:

- Calling `process.wait()` after running `process = subprocess.Popen(...)`
- Using `subprocess.call` instead of `Popen`
- Using `subprocess.check_call` instead of `Popen`

Comment: Seems to cover all options, though none worked for me, probably coz of a deeper problem on my side.

Comment: @Vegetto how isn't it working?  Are they still being executed in the wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start the process like:

```
process = subprocess.call( ["<path to exe>", "-u", "username", "-p",  password, query], 
                                 shell = False)
```

This way the main process sleeps until the subprocess ends, but you don't get output.

Comment: The row still seems to be locked, though I can't see the error anymore. It may be some DB side error, too.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how the result looks, one way would be to use wait():

```
process = subprocess.Popen( "<path to exe> -u " + username + " -p "+ password +" " + query, 
                             shell = True,
                             stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
retcode = process.wait()
```